# Use list values in for loop

Tags: r

I have a `table4` with 25 columns and I do want to subset this table for 7 values in column `Job..R` to get 7 individual tables.

```
for(i in 1:7) {
  x = NULL
  x = list(1 == "14047/2", 2 == "18331/3", 3 == "18331/4", 4 == "24889/3", 
           5 == "24889/4", 6 == "24889/5", 7 == "24889/9")
  View(i)
  a = subset(table4, Job..R == x[i])
  b = mean(a[ ,13])
  View(a)
  View(b)
  save(b, file="i.Rda") #ideally save .Rda file with used Job..R
}
```

I created a for loop from 1 to 7 and a list with names 1 to 7 and to each name I have assigned a value from column `Job..R` I want to subset to.

At the moment this loop does 7 loops (that is what I want) and creates me 7 tables with the 25 columns including headers but without content. How can I get the content into the new tables?
And how can I save the new tables with a specific file name for each table. Ideally the specific file name is the number from column `Job..R` I used to subset with.
Many thanks in advance!!

Johannes

Comment: hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.   Please consider rewording your question as it lacks clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `==` inside your `list()` call as it *compares* values rather than assigning list items. `x` using your current code is just a list of `FALSE` values because:

```
1=="14047/2"
#[1] FALSE
```

Try this instead:

```
x = list("14047/2","18331/3","18331/4","24889/3", "24889/4","24889/5","24889/9")
```

Also, you will need to `paste0` together your file name so that the `i` can be interpreted properly:

```
save(b, file=paste0(i,".Rda") )
```

Comment: Thank you, the sub setting works now, but when I do the `save` command then the console comes up with the following: `115:   save(a, paste0(i,".Rda") #ideally save .Rda file with used Job..R
116: }
     ^` It complaints about the closing bracket, `@thelatemail`

Comment: @Johannes - did you add a second closing bracket just like the example code I posted? It doesn't look like your code has one.

Comment: I found this as well and tried to delete my comment, but now the following error message appears: `Error in save(a, paste0(i, ".Rda")) : 
  object ‘paste0(i, ".Rda")’ not found`.

Comment: @thelatemail that last line should be save(b, file=paste0(i,".Rda") )